# Why this is invalid C code?

Tags: c, lvalue, pre-increment

If `x` is of type `int`, for what I understand, `++x` is a lvalue, so

```
++x = 5;
```

is valid. But the compiler doesn't like it. It days that

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment

What is happening here? Isn't `++x` an lvalue?

Comment: `++x` is a lvalue in C++, not C.

Comment: What would it even mean?  What is it that's being assigned a value of 5?  Does `x` get a value 1 more than it had, or does it get a value of 5, or what?  This is like `(x = x + 1) = 5`.

Answer (score 3):

++x vaguely translates to x = x + 1.
It does not act as a lvalue ( in C ) so you cannot assign it any value.